# how to style this django form?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head %}
{% endblock head %}
{% block body %}
    <div>
        <div class="container" id="outer">
    <div>
        <h1>User Login Form</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form method="post">

            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block">Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

I had made this code without using `forms.py` and getting trouble for styling the `forms.so`. Please help me solve my problem.

Comment: what is the problem? what do you except it to display and what are you seeing instead?

Comment: i am seeing a simple form containing fields username and password only.I want to style it to look better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you display for forms as

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

you are simply displaying all form elements in their own paragraph tags.

One way to style your forms is to display each form element in their own divs like so,

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div>
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Having them in their own divs allows you better control on their disply.
Similarly, you can give for elements their own classes in your definition in forms.py. For example, if I had a Login form with a username field I could do the following

```
username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

This would create an HTML element that looks like this

```
<div> username <input type="text" class="form-control"></div>
```

You can then style your forms by using the correct classes. More information here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/

Comment: is it possible to style that only much of code means {{form.as_p}}

Comment: i want to style only in built login form which i got from django.contrib.auth.views import login

Comment: In what way do you want to style the form? because {{form.as_p}} is going to generate all the html of the form, and those have to be customized in forms.py as shown

Comment: means i want to my login page to look more attractive